# Propositional logic notation by problem solving

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus

I'm having a hard time understanding some propositional logic notation in the following problem:

> Given the formula $F = (¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q)$, define the formula's truth value
>   $A_{B}(F)$ by applying definitions to $A_{B}$ step by step until you
>   reach the valuations $B(p)$ and $B(q)$.
>
> The first step:   $A_{B}(F) = A_{B}((¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q))$
>   $=f_{∨}(A_{B}(¬p ∧ ¬q),A_{B}(p ∧ ¬q))$

Looking at the first step, I have no clue why we would rewrite it the way it is shown.

Why would you replace $A_{B}((...) ∨ (...))$ with $f_{∨}(A_{B}(...),A_{B}(...))$. What does this mean in English?

What could follow as the next step? Should I now work on the 'split' parts?

Where can I read more about the notation used in the above problem? I mean not the simple $¬, ∧, ∨$ but how to read and write more complex formulas in the process of solving a problem like in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand $f_#(A_B(p),A_B(q))$ is another way of writing $A_B(p#q)$ where $#$ is some Boolean operator.

Comment: Do you know of any textbooks or online sources that use the same notation so I can read more? Why do we need to rewrite something to mean the same thing? How does it help us?